# We need to find unit vector along the reflected ray

Tags: homework-and-exercises, reflection, vectors

A ray of light on a plane mirror comes along a vector $i+j-k$

The normal on incidence point is along $i+j$

we need to find  unit vector along the reflected ray.

I am not able to solve and draw the picture. could any one explain me what is going on?

answer given is $-{1\over\sqrt{3}}(i+j+k)$

Answer (score 3):

The general thinking that you will find useful is the following. Suppose the incident ray is along vector $X$ and the normal to the mirror is $N$. Then resolve $X$ into components tangential $X_\parallel$ and orthogonal $X_\perp$ to the mirror.

$$X_\perp = \frac{\left<X,\,N\right>}{|N|^2} N\tag{1}$$

and, naturally:

$$X_\parallel = X - \frac{\left<X,\,N\right>}{|N|^2} N\tag{2}$$

A reflexion in the mirror leaves the component parallel to the surface as it is, whilst switching the sign of the orthogonal component (think of a ball thrown at a wall). So, the reflected ray, from (1) and (2) runs along:

$$X_r = X_\parallel - X_\perp = X-2\frac{\left<X,\,N\right>}{|N|^2} N$$

which you can use to find your reflected ray by setting $X = \hat{i}+\hat{j}-\hat{k}$ and $N = \hat{i}+\hat{j}$; you'll then need to normalise your result $X_r$ (which, by my reckonning gives the stated answer).

Comment: This is a much nicer and more efficient approach than what I was doing: rotating by $\pi$ around the normal...

Answer (score 1):

The Normal To Mirror is Defined by vector i+j. let i-j as  reference surface as surface will be along direction of vector that is perpendicular to normal.Now ray i+j-k falls on it making some angle with the normal due to additional component in z direction then any reflected ray will make same angle with the normal and that will be along direction of i+j+k.This is because angle that can be calculated by tan inverse formula will remain same if modulus has been taken.As it is unit 1/sqrt(3) is in result and negative sign is because it is reflected